# How to build 2 apps with the same project in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've recently just imported my eclipse project into Android Studio, I haven't convert it into gradle yet. So some forum that offers me solution from gradle is not working. My problem is I have 2 application, where both has some slight difference. I want to use the same project when I deploy the application. I've tried to change the project name but that doesn't help. The moment the new application is installed, the previous version is overwritten. I thought of making some changes to the Manifest file(not sure if this is the right thing to do) but in android studio, I can't seem to locate where the file is. Please help.

Regards,
Dexter

Comment: Android Studio has an option for Import Eclipse projects. Have you tried it?

Comment: I recommend you to use Build Variants for 2 separate versions of practically the same app. But I wrote an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your application needs to have a different package name for it to be treated as a different app.

So instead of

```
com.yourcompany.apps.yourapp
```

You write 
`com.yourcompany.apps.yourapp1` and
`com.yourcompany.apps.yourapp2`

You can do that in your `AndroidManifest.XML` in the `manifest` tag

```
package="com.yourcompany.apps.yourapp1"
```

---

Also, instead of 2 separate apps, try seeing if you can solve this using [Build variants](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants) and product flavors.

Comment: I've tried to change the package name from AndroidManifest.xml before importing the project into AndroidStudio but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use flavors on your build.gradle

```
productFlavors {
        flavorName {
            minSdkVersion 19
            applicationId 'you.package.name'
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName 'version_name'
        }
    }
```

Also you can modify a file with different changes by just adding a source folder for the flavor.

```
app
|--src
  |--main
  |--flavorName
```